# Animated series about a team shrinking in size in a ship that enters human body to fight aliens

Tags: story-identification, animated-series

I think it was a japanese animated series. In the series a humanoid alien civilization is dying out, but they don't understand why. They discover Earth and notice that humans don't have the same problem. So aliens decide to investigate humans.

The investigation goes like this: aliens board a ship, shrink themselves and their ship to microscopic levels, enter human body, disable some random organ and observe the result (what a genius plan!). The human subject collapses and everyone is very sad.

But (surprise-surprise!) humans also have the shrinking technology, so they board their own ship, shrink themselves to the same size as aliens, enter the suffering person's body, fight the aliens (with lasers!) and undo the damage (or cause more damage themselves, my memory fails me here).

Comment: In roughly which year or decade did you watch this, and when do you think it might've been made?

Comment: @LogicDictates Just found it via reddit. It aired in 1986.

Comment: I was thinking that the humans should have shrunk themselves down to be small enough to inject themselves into the already shrunken aliens and randomly turn off alien organs.  And then the aliens shrink themselves even more ....

Comment: @PeterM What a plot twist! :O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, I found it, it's [Wonder Beat Scramble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wonder_Beat_Scramble) and it seems that I misremembered a lot of things, but now I have plans <strike>for the upcoming weekend!</strike> screw that, I'm watching it now!

Indeed, it's a japanese animated series by Osamu Tezuka. Aired in 1986 (damn, I'm old). Judging by the age of the main character, its main audience is supposed to be 13 years old kids (and the 37 years old people like me...).

The anime has a medical theme, with explanations of the workings of a human body, mixed with a sci-fi theme which includes lasers, missiles and evil aliens (because otherwise it would get boooring).

Of course, the moral of the story is that we should strive to become doct... take care of the environment. "Wait, what?!" you'll ask? Well, yes, because logic.

It's a fun anime :)

Comment: :) If you would, post enough detail that it would answer the question if you weren't the original person questioning, ideally so that it would help others in the future. And don't forgot to accept in 44 hours.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I posted some... details. Not sure if they'll help others in the future or will get me banned from the stackexchange network... or both. Anyway, I'm happy I found what I was looking for.